# SQL Server 2012: CONVERT Char to Timestamp returns invalid year

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 2 clients with **Microsoft SQL Server 2012** installed.
When I run this Query:

```
SELECT StartTime
FROM RecordLog
WHERE CONVERT(timestamp, StartTime) >= CONVERT(timestamp, '03/11/2016 18:00:00') 
AND CONVERT(timestamp, StartTime) <= CONVERT(timestamp, '03/19/2016 05:59:59')  
ORDER BY id ASC
```

The first client return correct data.
But the second client returns data with the correct month and date on different years.

Comment: Given info doesn't help,can you share more details on clients,what is the correct data you are seeing and what is the second client returning

Comment: use the third parameter of the convert function to specify the conversion format. Read MSDN about the function

Comment: Uh, `timestamp` is not equivalent to a `datetime`.  It is quite unclear what you are doing.  (Hint:  lookup `rowversion` in the SQL Server documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

First, if `StartTime` is a datetime, you can just use appropriate string literals for the comparison:

```
SELECT StartTime
FROM RecordLog
WHERE StartTime >= '2016-03-11T18:00:00' AND
      StartTime < '2016-03-10T06:00:00'
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Explicit conversions for the constants are not necessary.  Of course, you can use them if they make you feel better.  (And, the "T" can be a space, but the "T" is part of the ISO 8601 standard.)